# What is another phrase for Tips and Tricks?

Tags: terminology, slang

I'm creating some training material and I have a mental block. I'm just looking for more words to use instead of Tips and Tricks...those get old. :) Like "Learn the Latest Tips and Tricks on your iPhone". I'm training on Microsoft applications and trying to think outside the box.

Comment: Could you provide some context or examples of how it will be used? I'm thinking of *best practices*, *knowledge base*, or *pitfalls to avoid*

Comment: Like "Learn the Latest Tips and Tricks on your Iphone"....I'm training on Microsoft applications and trying to think outside the box.

Comment: I most often see "Tips and Techniques".

Comment: possibly related to this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264226/another-word-for-lifehacks

Comment: Handy facts and tidbits.

Comment: *pointers* ... which is usually a more critical form of *tips*.  Also in that line is *techniques*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after something reasonably formal where the tips are not trivial in length, then I would suggest perhaps "**Useful techniques**". This seems to be reasonably commonly used (*see this Google query: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=useful+techniques for the sorts of examples; there are 238 mil results*)

"**Handy**" adds a bit more of a friendly and informal to nature to it.

Or if you don't think it is too blunt for your use-case, then "**Advice**"